# div width 90% with 5% padding creates right border on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad

When i make a **div** that has a width of **100%**
and inside that div i place **another div** with a width of **90%**, that has a **padding of 5%** (100% in total) it creates a **border on the right hand side of the screen**.

So far this 'bug' is only on the iPad (1 and first retina). Not on desktop. And not on mobile Android.

When i remove

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

or any equivalent of the viewport I don't have that problem. But of course it has to be there.

Is this normal behaviour? Or have I stumbled upon some kind of bug?

On the website I use **Eric's Meyer's** css reset,
on the fiddle i use the *** {margin / padding}** reset. If that has to do anything with it

I thank you for your help! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Empi/h7ck6/

http://migueldebruyne.be/test/

Comment: That is a little strange. I have an iPad Air and it does seem to cause a border to the right. Shouldn't do like you said... Very odd, not sure what would cause that but I guess its a bug of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply `box-sizing: border-box;` and `width: 100%;` to inner div

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

#aDiv {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/h7ck6/2/

I can't test this in your demo site but in jsfiddle seems to work on ipad

Comment: Indeed this solution works! I don't like the fact that i have to change everything on the project I'm working on just to fix this bug on iPad. But for now this is ok :)